# Is there a way to make a sidebar with the default Bootstrap 4 widget Yii2

Tags: php, css, yii, yii2

I want to know if there is a way to make a sidebar with Bootstrap 4 default NavBar widget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-widget-sidenav

Helped me for this one, realy usefull.